# Nested Installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Is it possible to do nested instllations of msi's in Visual studio 2008 setup project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only one MSI can execute at a time.

What you need is a 'bootstrapper' EXE to run each MSI in sequence.